# Sync 5 Raspberry Pi3 B+

Tags: pi-3, video, relay

Hi I'm new to programming and Raspberry Pi. What I am looking for is what platform I need to play in sync a unique video-loop for each RPi (off a USB). I have installed Raspian. Each is connected to its own CRT monitor via RCA output.

I see screenly, kodi, omxplayer (autoplay via a browser), GPIO,...

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Especially if there is a LAN option to trigger them and then maintain sync and then loop/repeat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I saw a sync addon in kodi, but I still have not got kodi to work.

Comment: Have you considered using `cron` to do this? As long as each of your RPis has the same time, an entry in each of their `crontab`s would start the video at the same time.